# proper format for pdfauthor in case of two authors

Tags: hyperref, pdf, metadata

Assuming a paper has two authors: John Smith and Sally Sixpack, what's the "right" (i.e., most useful) way to put them into the `pdfauthor` option of `hyperref`? Choices:

- `pdfauthor={John Smith and Sally Sixpack}`
- `pdfauthor={John Smith, Sally Sixpack}`
- `pdfauthor={John Smith; Sally Sixpack}`
- ... (your choice goes here) ...

There are absolutely no "hard" external requirements on the paper in this respect. My only "soft" wish is to help the potential readers. Initially, these are the reviewers; finally, these are the folks finding their way to the paper through the various Web search engines and through Oxford University Press (https://academic.oup.com/journals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pdfauthor` entry goes into the Author field in a PDF file's document information dictionary. The PDF specification only says that  this is a text string, for the "name of the person who created the document".

What's the most *useful* format when you have multiple authors? Journal articles or books will have authoritative information in the DOI and publisher databases. Search engines don't seem to surface the Author metadata to users, though they probably do index it. The most likely other use I can think of for the Author field is bibliography management software that extract information from PDF files, such as Zotero. Zotero handles the format "John Smith and Sally Sixpack" well.

(Note that you can also provide PDF metadata using the XMP format, which is much more tightly specified and allows you to provide other relevant information such as the licence for the content, using the `xmpincl` package.)

Comment: Out of interest: What would you recommend for three authors? I can see merits in the verbose `Jane Smith and Anne Elk and William Riter` because that can just be copied directly into a `.bib` file and does not look to bad for those who actually read the metadata themselves (I'm assuming that Google et al. are clever enough to parse the `and`s here, but I'm sure they are.).

Comment: Yes, I use `Jane Smith and Anne Elk and William Riter` and Zotero at least can parse that from the PDF file automatically.